# Groovy - insert string in every last entry of group

Tags: list, groovy

Original List:

```
def list = [[category: "DLF", name: "some name one"],
        [category: "EF", name: "some name two"],
        [category: "RW", name: "some name five"],
        [category: "EF", name: "some name four"],
        [category: "DLF", name: "some name two"],
        [category: "RW", name: "some name three"]]
```

Is there a way to group it by category and sort it by category but is should be exactly arrange as "EF", "DLF", "RW" and I also want to insert new element in every last index of the category just like this one:

```
def list = [[category: "EF", name: "some name two"],
            [category: "EF", name: "some name four"],
            [category: "EF", name: "others"],
            [category: "DLF", name: "some name one"],
            [category: "DLF", name: "some name two"],
            [category: "DLF", name: "others"],
            [category: "RW", name: "some name three"],
            [category: "RW", name: "some name five"],
            [category: "RW", name: "others"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can define the order you want the results in:

```
def requiredOrder = ['EF', 'DLF', 'RW']
```

Then, you can group, sort, and add the others element:

```
def result = list.groupBy { it.category }
    .sort { requiredOrder.indexOf(it.key) }
    .collectMany { k, v -> v + [category: k, name: 'others'] }
```

The required result will be in the variable `result`

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same as from @tim_yates, but slightly more straight-forward:

```
def requiredOrder = ['EF', 'DLF', 'RW']

def result = ( list + requiredOrder.collect{ [ category:it, name: "others"] } )
             .sort{ requiredOrder.indexOf it.category }
```